# Forking in windows

Tags: fork

I am looking in to the details of different fork implementation methods. Following link is referred for fork implementation,
http://doxygen.scilab.org/5.3/d0/d8f/forkWindows_8c_source.html . This fork implementation is by using ZwXXX functions exported by ntdll.

I could compile this in vs2012, windows 7 -64 bit machine. But on testing, I am not getting expected output. On forking, new child process is created, but this process immediately returns on resuming its suspended primary thread. It doesn't invoke fork call again. Have anyone tried to implement fork for windows? What am i missing in this code snippet? I have been researching different fork implementation for the past one week. Please help.

Comment: This fork implementation is working as expected with win-32 Release build. But fails with win-64 build and with debug build.

Comment: Its great that you spent a week on researching fork implementations.  Spend another 6 months.  You will be a forkstar.

Answer (score -1):

I had also the similar issue while porting the fork api to windows and i used a temporary solution as:

- Add Sleep () after the fork in child process.
- Run the parent process by ctrl+F5.
- Then attach the child process to the VS debugger.
- Continue debugging using the F5 key.
- We can also attach the parent process to the VS debugger.

Is there any better solution for debugging the forked child process.

Comment: fork is an OS dependent function.  It is a UNIX construct that does not exist in windows natively.  It also has several variants in UNIX and linux which make its behavior unpredictable.  When you say make fork work on windows, not only dont you understand the windows kernel, you dont realize that the behavior of fork is not consistent on unix, so what exactly are you wanting to do specifically?